# Chained Observable after takeWhile completes is not being called?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have the following methods which should be called like this:

1. `registerDomain` should be called and should return an `operationId`
2. After `10` seconds, `getOperationDetail` should be called passing in the `operationId`
3. `getOperationDetail` should be called every `10` seconds until `successful` is returned.
4. Once `getOperationDetail` finishes, `createRecordSets` should be called.
5. Finally, `getChangeStatus` should be called until it returns `INSYNC`
6. If any of the api calls throw an exception, how can I handle the error on the client side?

The following code below calls registerDomain and getOperationDetail, but after getOperationDetail completes, it does not move onto createRecordSets.

```
  registerDomain(domain) {
    return this._adminService.registerDomain(domain)
      .concatMap(operation => this.getOperationDetail(operation.OperationId))
      .concatMap(() => this._adminService.createRecordSets(domain));
  }

  getOperationDetail(operationId) {
    return Observable.interval(10000)
      .mergeMap(() => this._adminService.getOperationDetail(operationId))
      .takeWhile((info) => info.Status.Value !== 'SUCCESSFUL');
  }
  createRecordSets(caseWebsiteUrl) {
    return this._adminService.createRecordSets(caseWebsiteUrl.Url)
        .concatMap(registerId => this.getChangeStatus(registerId));
  }

  getChangeStatus(registerId) {
    return Observable.interval(5000)
      .mergeMap(() => this._adminService.getChange(registerId))
      .takeWhile((info) => info.ChangeInfo.Status.Value !== 'INSYNC');
  }
```

I updated `getOperationDetail` to use the `first` operator:

```
  getOperationDetail(operationId) {
    return Observable.interval(3000)
      .mergeMap(() => this._adminService.getOperationDetail(operationId))
      .first((info) =>  info.Status.Value === 'SUCCESSFUL')

  }
```

Now it does in fact call `createRecordSets`, however, after `createRecordSets`, it continues to call `getOperationDetail` about 13 times and eventually calls `getChangeStatus`.  The way I was looking at it, I thought it would:

1. Call `getOperationDetail` until it receives a `SUCCESS`.
2. Call `createRecordSets` one time.
3. Call `getChangeStatus` until it receives an `INSYNC`
4. Done.

Why the additional calls?

I changed the registerDomain to look like this:

```
 registerDomain(domain) {
    return this._adminService.registerDomain(domain)
      .concatMap(operation => this.getOperationDetail(operation.OperationId))
        .concatMap((op) => this.createRecordSets(op));
```

Before I had the `.concatMap((op) => this.createRecordSets(op))` chained right after `this.getOperationDetail`.  Once I moved it outside that, it started working as expected. I am unsure why though.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `takeWhile` meets a value that satisfies a specified criteria, it completes the observable without propagating the value. It means that the next chained operator will not receive the value and will not invoke its callback.

Suppose that in your example the first two calls to `this._adminService.getOperationDetail(...)` result in a non-successful status and the third call succeeds. It means that an observable returned by `getOperationDetail()` would produce only two `info` values each of which having non-successful status. And what might be also important, the next chained `concatMap` operator would invoke its callback per each of those non-successful values, meaning that `createRecordSets()` would be called twice. I suppose that you might want to avoid that.

I would suggest to use `first` operator instead:

```
getOperationDetail(operationId) {
    return Observable.interval(10000)
        .concatMap(() => this._adminService.getOperationDetail(operationId))
        .first(info => info.Status.Value !== 'SUCCESSFUL');
}
```

This way `getOperationDetail()` would produce only a single "successful" value as soon as `this._adminService.getOperationDetail(operationId)` succeeds. The [`first`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/first.ts) operator emits the first value of the source observable that matches the specified condition and then completes.

And when it comes to error handling, [`catch`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/catch.ts) or [`retry`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/retry.ts) operators might be useful.

**Update:**

The unexpected behavior you have faced (`getOperationDetail()` keeps being called after `first()` completes) seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2455) in `rxjs`. As described in [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2459),

> every take-ish operator (one that completes earlier than its source Observable), will keep subscribing to source Observable when combined with operator that prolongs subscription (here switchMap).

Both `first` and `takeWhile` are examples of such take-ish operators and operators that "prolong" subscription are, for example, `switchMap`, `concatMap` and `mergeMap`. In the following example numbers will be kept logging while inner observable of `concatMap` is emitting values:

```
var takeish$ = Rx.Observable.interval(200)
    // will keep logging until inner observable of `concatMap` is completed
    .do(x => console.log(x))
    .takeWhile(x => x < 2);

var source = takeish$
    .concatMap(x => Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(10))
    .subscribe();
```

It looks like this can be worked around by turning an observable containing such a take-ish operator into a higher-order observable — in a similar way as you've done:

```
var takeish$ = Rx.Observable.interval(200)
    // will log only 0, 1, 2
    .do(x => console.log(x))
    .takeWhile(x => x < 2);

var source = Rx.Observable.of(null)
    .switchMap(() => takeish$)
    .concatMap(x => Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(1))
    .subscribe();
```

**Update 2:**

It seems that the bug described above still exists as of rxjs version 5.4.2. It affects, for example, whether or not the source observable of the `first` operator will be unsubscribed when `first` meets the specified condition. When `first` operator is immediately followed by `concatMap`, its source observable will not be unsubscribed and will keep emitting values until inner observable of `concatMap` completes. In your case it means that `this._adminService.getOperationDetail()` would keep being called until observable returned by `createRecordSets()` would have completed.

Here's your example simplified to illustrate the behavior:

```js
function registerDomain() {
    return Rx.Observable.of("operation")
        .concatMap(() => getOperationDetail()
            .concatMap(() => Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(5)));
}

function getOperationDetail() {
    return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
        // console.log() instead of the actual service call
        .do(x => console.log(x))
        .first(x => x === 2);
}

registerDomain().subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

If we expand the inner observable of the first `concatMap` operator, we will get the following observable:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .do(x => console.log(x))
    .first(x => x === 2)
    .concatMap(() => Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(5));
```

Notice that `first` is immediately followed by `concatMap` which prevents the source observable of the `first` operator (i.e. `interval(100).do(x => console.log(x)`) from being unsubscribed. Values will keep being logged (or in your case, service calls will keep being sent) until the inner observable of `concatMap` (i.e. `interval(200).take(5)`) completes.

If we modify the example above and move the second `concatMap` out of the inner observable of the first `concatMap`, `first` will not be chained with it any more and will unsubscribe from the source observable as soon as the condition is satisfied, meaning that interval will stop emitting values and no more numbers will be logged (or no more service requests will be sent):

```js
function registerDomain() {
    return Rx.Observable.of("operation")
        .concatMap(() => getOperationDetail())
        .concatMap(() => Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(5));
}

function getOperationDetail() {
    return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
        // console.log() instead of the actual service call
        .do(x => console.log(x))
        .first(x => x === 2);
}

registerDomain().subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Inner observable in such a case can be expanded simply to:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .do(x => console.log(x))
    .first(x => x === 2)
```

Notice that `first` is not anymore followed by `concatMap`.

It is also worth mentioning that in both cases observable returned by `registerDomain()` produces exactly the same values and if we move logging from `do()` operator to `subscribe()`, the same values will be written to the console in both cases:

```
registerDomain.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Hi, I tried first and it works, but I am running into an issue.  I updated my post with it.

Comment: I think I managed to reproduce unexpected behavior that you described, I will update the answer soon. In a nutshell, `first()` doesn't seem to unsubscribe from the source observable even after the specified condition is met, see [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2455) for details.

Comment: @xaisoft, I updated the answer with the bug description and a possible way to work around it. Frankly, this bug was a big surprise for me : )

Comment: Hi Sergey, I appreciate the answer.  I also posted a question with a simple example and got the following response.  It looks like it is fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332224/2665434

Comment: @xaisoft, the other question you posted is absolutely valid, but it has nothing to do with the bug you have described. I am rather sure that the bug still exists in the current version of rxjs (5.4.2 as of now) and it is related to whether or not `first` operator is chained with `concatMap` operator. I updated my answer with more details and a couple of runnable snippets to illustrate the issue.