# rxjs first operator is being repeatedly called?

Tags: rxjs, observable

If I use, 2 gets printed to the console every 3 seconds:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(3000)
.mergeMap(() => Rx.Observable.of(3))
.concatMap(()=>Rx.Observable.of(2).first(x=>x == 2))
.subscribe((x)=>console.log(x))
```

If I use, 2 gets printed to the console only one time:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(3000)
.mergeMap(() => Rx.Observable.of(3))
.concatMap(()=>Rx.Observable.of(2))
.first(x=>x == 2)
.subscribe((x)=>console.log(x))
```

The difference is where I chained the first operator, but I don't understand the flow of the chain.  I thought in both cases, it should only print 2 once since I have an observable of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused with the `first()` operator. The definition of `first()` is:

> Returns the first element of an **observable sequence** that satisfies the condition in the predicate, or a default value if no such element exists. If no default value is given, then onError will be called.

Note the word *observable sequence*, aka stream. The difference of the two scenarios are as follow:

#### Scenario 1:

Your `first()` is applied to an observable that returns a value 2. Nothing is done to the `Observable.interval()` stream, which keeps on emitting an event every 3 seconds. That is why your console never stops logging.

#### Scenario 2:

The `first()` is applied to an `Observable.interval()` that **continuously** emits an event, every 3 seconds. Hence, your `first()` operator basically chops the sequence (or stop it) as soon as it finds the fulfilling condition, which is `x===2`. When the condition is met, the stream *ends*, it then returns the FIRST element of that sequence. Hence your console only logs one time.

Comment: Thanks...Makes more sense now